# Matrix constrained-optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

The optimization I'm having problem with is following:
$$\text{minimize}_x\quad m^⊺x$$
$$\text{subject to }Ax\leq b$$
Suppose A is nonsingular (i.e. if $x$ is of size $n$, the $A$ is $n\times n$ and can be inverted.)

The question I have is what condition must hold in order for there to be a finite solution to this problem? What is the optimal value of the objective function? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is always feasible for $x = A^{-1}b$ so we are interested in the conditions on the boundedness of the problem. If primal is feasible and bounded, dual infeasible is impossible. The dual problem is:

$\max \ b^{\top}u \\ \text{s.t.} \\ A^{\top}u = m, \\ u \leq 0.$

where the feasibility condition is $A^{-\top}m \leq 0$. So if this holds, then the primal problem is bounded.